# Get single value field_view_field

Tags: 7, entities, media

I am using `field_view_field()` to render a product image.
I have a condition where I want to display only one image for the product not other images of that product. How can I do this?

Comment: ok... you did not ask a question, all you did was state facts.

Comment: I guess you want to ask how to display only the first image only with `field_view_field()` on the multiple value image field. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your view template file:

```
print fields['your_field_name']->content;
```